# ROR installation on CentOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, centos

I am new to ruby on rails. I tried installing ruby, rails & rvm using this command:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

It worked fine but, now I am trying to check the version of ruby & rails (`ruby -v`, `rails -v`) it says `command not found`.

This is what it shows (I have pasted last few lines only...) :

```
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.7.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for rdoc-3.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for railties-3.2.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.2.7...



 * To start using RVM you need to run `source /home/betteruse/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

  * To start using rails you need to run `rails new <project_dir>`.

[betteruse@BL-58 ~]$ ruby -v
bash: ruby: command not found
[betteruse@BL-58 ~]$ rails -v
bash: rails: command not found
```

Can anyone help ??? 
Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try rvm reload

if still not work then insert following lines to your .bashrc or .bash_profile file

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

also make sure you have run `curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails` from home directory

Comment: Hey thanks Loken.. I reinstalled it from Home directory.. It is working fine now..

Comment: So can you please mark this answer as accepted so it will be helpful to newbies of Rails for development setup :)